# How to create a card token from stripe in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, stripe-payments

I want to create a card token in the client-side code (flutter) and send it to the server-side (laravel backend) to create a charge. The only statement I found in `flutter_stripe` that's supposed to do so is `Stripe.instance.createToken(CreateTokenParams.card(params: CardTokenParams()));` as the docs say. But it doesn't take the card number, expiration date, or cvc. It takes stuff like name, address, etc. How to create a card token?

Comment: [Token and Charges API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api) are legacy and deprecated integrations that they shouldn't be used. Payment Intent with Payment Sheet integration should be used instead. Please refer to the integration guide [here](https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet).

Answer (score 1):

//------------------------ Generate Stripe Token----------------------//

// Setup For android

// Add flutter_stripe: ^9.4.0

// In android/app/build.gradle ----> minSdkVersion 21

// In android/build.gradle ----> Use Kotlin version 1.5.0 and above

// In android/app/src/main/res/values ----> Download the values from flutter_stripe and replace with downloaded one

// In android/app/src/main/res/values-night ----> Download the values from flutter_stripe and replace with downloaded one

// In android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity ----> Add this line under the FlutterActivity ---> import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

// Setup For iOS

// In ios/Podfile ----> Change platform :ios, '13.0' or above

// At last add Stripe.publishableKey = "Your_Key"; in your main initState();

```
Future<String?> generateStripeToken({required String cvv}) async{

// This is used to separate month and year

var prAge = expiryDate.value.split("/");
var month = prAge[0].trim();
var year = prAge[1].trim();

CardTokenParams cardParams = CardTokenParams(type: TokenType.Card, name:nameController.text,);

await Stripe.instance.dangerouslyUpdateCardDetails(CardDetails(
  number: cardNumber.value,
  cvc: cvv,
  expirationMonth: int.tryParse(month),
  expirationYear: int.tryParse("20$year"),
));

try {
  TokenData token = await Stripe.instance.createToken(CreateTokenParams.card(params: cardParams),);
  print("Flutter Stripe token  ${token.toJson()}");
  return token.id;
} on StripeException catch (e)  {
  Utils.errorSnackBar(e.error.message);
  print("Flutter Stripe error ${e.error.message}");
}
return null;}
```

// Now call this function on your screen

//String? tokenId = await controller.generateStripeToken(cvv: controller.cvvCode.value);

//print("Strike Token Id --------------------> $tokenId");

//To create card id and token make future list type and return

//return [token.card?.id,token.id] ;